# checkout-session not created-android paypal sdk

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

```
09-08 13:37:45.336 12937-15114/com.example.rajitha.paypal E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:422,exception:
09-08 13:37:45.336 12937-15114/com.example.rajitha.paypal E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"name":"PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR","debug_id":"f72dd01368fd2","message":"checkout-session not created","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR"}
09-08 13:37:45.336 12937-12937/com.example.rajitha.paypal E/paypal.sdk: PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR
```

> I created two sandbox personal and business accounts for testing.The app is successfully logged using the personal account.But can not proceed the transaction .I have attached the screen with error message.

[image]

Comment: have you got the solution ?

Comment: Yes Rjz .It was a problem with my personal account.

Comment: what was an issue with a personal account can you please explore more about it